# Gallery view scrolling is not working when i set itemclicklistener for imageview?

Tags: android, gallery

I'm using gallery widget with an imageview and textview. I am able to setonitemclicklistener for galleryview, but i want to set clicklistener for an imageview. When I try to set, galleryview's scroll is not working.

```
public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter  {

    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    private  String[] mImageURLs = {
            "http://www.example1.com",
            "http://www.example2.com",
            "http://www.example3.com",
            "http://www.example4.com",
            "http://www.example5.com",
            "http://www.example6.com"
    };


    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.menusliderinflate, null);
        v.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);
        int score = getLevelScore(position + 1);
         Adpimgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.level4image);
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.level4score);
        RelativeLayout holder=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout01);

        if (score > 0) {
            scoreView.setText(score + "/18");
            Adpimgview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FAAE67"));
        } else {
            scoreView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(position!=0)Adpimgview.setAlpha(100);
        }

        Adpimgview.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);

        Adpimgview.setTag(mImageURLs[position]);
        Log.d("dd","Inside adapter" + mImageURLs[position]);

        Adpimgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        // imgView.setLayoutParams(new
        // Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Here i set onclicklistener to imageview

```
        Adpimgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WorldSelected = position + 1;
                Log.d("dd","world selected"+WorldSelected);
                levelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                outerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.levelbackground);
                worldLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                backmenulayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                defaultmenulayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                updateScore(position + 1);

                onWorldItemClick();
            }
        });


        // imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return v;
    }
```

When i set onitemclicklistener for imageview which is inflated in galleryview ,Galleryview 's scroll is not working

Comment: if you have set android:clickable = "true" anywhere in your xml layout then remove this line from every where.

Comment: ontouch listener on any of your views you are using.

Comment: I placed my gallery widget in Linearlayout after that Relativelayout with imageview and text...

Answer (score 0):

Add setOnItemClickListener on Gallery Widget instead of getView() method.

```
Gallery.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Place you `getView()`onclick code into `OnItemClick` block.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            WorldSelected = position + 1;
            Log.d("dd","world selected"+WorldSelected);
            levelLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            outerLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.levelbackground);
            worldLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            backmenulayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            defaultmenulayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            updateScore(position + 1);

            onWorldItemClick();

    }
```

It should help you correctly!!

Comment: hey i got a call from your company for an interview. Tomorrow at 2:30